# No periodic solution using Bendixson's criterion and Global analysis.

Tags: dynamical-systems

**Theorem**: Let $Z:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ field defined in a simply connected set $U$. If $\mathrm{div} Z(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in U$, then $Z$ does not have any periodic orbit entirely contained in $U$.

**Application**: Let $X$ be a linear focus of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e $X(x)=A\cdot x$ where the eigenvalues of $A$ have non-zero real and imaginary part). Prove there is $\delta>0$ such that every field $Y$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfies
$$ \underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}{\sup} \left\Vert Y(x) \right\Vert\leq \delta $$
$$ \underset{\left\Vert x \right\Vert\leq 1}{\sup} \left\Vert DY(x) \right\Vert\leq \delta $$
does not admit any periodic orbit.

==================================================================

What I tried:

Since $X$ is a linear focus : $X(x_1, x_2)=P\underset{A}{\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cc}a+ib & 0 \\ 0 & a-ib \end{array}\right)}}P^{-1} \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1\\x_2 \end{array}\right)$, so $\mathrm{div} X(x) = 2a \neq 0$

For $\left\Vert x \right\Vert\leq 1,\, \left| \mathrm{div} Y(x) \right|=\left| \mathrm{TrD} Y(x) \right|\leq \left\Vert \mathrm{Tr} \right\Vert\left\Vert \mathrm{D}Y(x) \right\Vert \leq  \left\Vert \mathrm{Tr} \right\Vert\delta<\left| 2a \right|$ for a good choice of $\delta$. Here lies my **first issue**: I don't want the norm of the transpose ($ \left\Vert \mathrm{Tr} \right\Vert $) to be involved, but I don't know how to use another constant.

So we are sure there is no periodic orbit in the unit disk.

Now if we are out of the unit disk ($  \left\Vert x \right\Vert  > 1 $):

If $\left\Vert A \right\Vert <1$:

$\left\Vert \left( X+Y\right)(x) \right\Vert \leq \left\Vert A \right\Vert \left\Vert x \right\Vert + \delta \leq \left(\left\Vert A \right\Vert + \delta \right) \left\Vert x \right\Vert < \left\Vert x \right\Vert $ for $0<\delta<\frac{1-\left\Vert A \right\Vert}{2}$

**Second issue:** I would like to conclude that because of this property, any solution which started (i.e at $t=0$) outside of the unit disk eventually goes into the unit disk and never leaves it.

If $\left\Vert A \right\Vert >1$:
**Third issue:** I can consider $\left(-X-Y \right)$ to use the previous statement. Or can I?

**Fourth issue:** I don't know how to handle the case $\left\Vert A \right\Vert =1$

Comment: What does $Y(x) \le \delta$ mean? Sure $Y(x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: So sorry I meant $\left\Vert Y(x) \right\Vert$. I am going to edit this. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you want to prove that any system that is close to a hyperbolic focus in $C^1$ metric also doesn't have a closed orbit?

Comment: Well perhaps. Can you precise what the definition of $\mathcal{C}^1$ metric is?

Comment: By definition, two mappings $T_1$ and $T_2$ are $\delta$-close in compact domain $D$ in $C^1$-metric if $\sup \limits_{p\in D} \vert\!\vert T_1(p) - T_2(p) \vert\!\vert < \delta$ and $\sup \limits_{p\in D} \left \vert \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial T_1}{\partial x_i} \right \vert < \delta $ for all $i$.

Comment: Ok so what I need to prove is weaker since we assume $\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}{\sup} \left\Vert Y(x) \right\Vert\leq \delta$ instead of only on a compact. But I am curious about such a proof.